# How does JWT do Authentication

Tags: javascript, json, jwt

`JWT` official docs say that `JWT` is most commonly used for Authentication.

> **Authentication** is the process of determining whether someone or something is, in fact, who or what it is declared to be.

Now if my server gets a request from the client and header of that request contains `JWT`. I will validate the `JWT` token with my secret key.

**If the `token` is valid, I can say for sure that:**

1. That token was generated by my server.
2. At the time of generating token user had provided their correct credentials. Meaning, if user claimed to be `John123`, they provided correct password for `John123` (server verified this, otherwise server return error response).

**If the `token` is valid, what I can NOT say for sure:**

1. On subsequent requests, if the user is claiming to `John123` (by passing `{userid:John123}` in request body) and they provide us with valid `JWT`, I can't say for sure that their claim is correct. Because its possible that user `Alice123` went into the `localstorage` of `John123` and stole the token and set it into their `localstorage`.

Now my question is how does `JWT` really validate that the users actually are what they are claiming to be. What I am missing here? Do I need to keep a mapping of `JWT`, `userid` and `ip` of client.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That is why it is called a "bearer" token: Anyone who brings the token is accepted. That's why it needs to be kept confidential -- use HTTPS! -- (and should also have a rather short lifetime)

Comment: This problem is also not specific to JWT. You have the same issue with an HTTP session cookie, for example.

Comment: @Thilo If I keep short expiry time say 30sec, won't I have to ask the user to login after every 30 sec? Can you explain?

Comment: @SKG for that purpose you should implement a refresh token mechanism. The refresh token is valid much longer and can be used to obtain a new access token

Comment: @jps: However, the refresh token also needs to be stored securely. So if the threat scenario is "compromised localStorage/physical access to unlocked device" then there is really not much you can do.

Comment: Another nice thing about refresh tokens is that the process to get a session token from them can be made more costly (since it happens only for every Nth request). So you can make them revocable for example (which a JWT itself cannot be).

Comment: @Thilo that's right, but it's not meant to solve that problem. It's just a means not to bother the user every couple of minutes with a login scrreen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well one step you are missing is that even after verifying the authenticity and claims (e.g. expiration date) of an incoming JWT, you still probably would have to hit your user database to make sure that the account is active and still exists.  So a JWT does not by itself solve the entire problem.

Regarding your actual question at the end, you generally have no idea about who the bearer of the JWT really is.  If Alice steals John's phone, then in fact she may be able to masquerade as him.  But keep in mind, if she does something this drastic, then she probably also has his credit and bank cards, and maybe some other passwords too.  No authentication process is completely safe.

With regard to lesser forms of theft, JWT is still robust.  For example, if someone tries to setup a man-in-the-middle attack to sniff your JWT, it won't work assuming your app encrypts that JWT with SSL.  And the real reason for JWT of course is that they are already signed with a key only known by the server to prevent the bearers from tampering with them.

Comment: Precision they are not encrypted but signed. You can encrypt them but you shouldn't pass any sensible information in them so it kind of useless.

Comment: Thanks. What if we create secretkey = somekey + user ip + their password hash? And use it to sign jwt. Won&#39;t it solve the problem of jwt stealing to a great extent?  It just came to my mind.

Comment: @SKG Clever idea, but what app or site do you know would hard code an IP address to a particular user?  For instance, as I switch from using Stack Overflow at home, on the train, and at work, my IP address changes several times.  Some sites like the AWS console _do_ check the IP address.  But this is unusual.

Answer (score 1):

JWT does not validate if the users are what they claim to be, because JWT is not an authentication framework. If you use JWT as an access token, you/your authentication middleware should make sure only to rely on the information in the token itself to identify the user and not any information in the request body.

Ususally you would store the user id or name in the token. The [`sub`claim](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2) can be used for that.

> The "sub" (subject) claim identifies the principal that is the
> subject of the JWT.  The claims in a JWT are normally statements
> about the subject.

The authentication middleware ususally only verifies, that the JWT itself has not been modified. But you won't recognize if Alice uses John's token.